# Google App Engine (Python) handle large number of writing tasks

Tags: python, performance, google-app-engine, queue, backend

I am reading a large amount of data from an API provider. Once get the response, I need to scan through and repackage the data and put into App Engine datastore. A particular big account will contain ~50k entries.

Every time I get some entries from the API, I will store 500 entries as a batch in a temp table and send the processing task to a queue. In case too many tasks get jammed inside one queue, I use 6 queues in total:

```
count = 0 
worker_number = 6
for folder, property in entries:
                    data[count] = {
                        # repackaging data here
                    }

                    count = (count + 1) % 500

                    if count == 0:
                        cache = ClientCache(parent=user_key, data=json.dumps(data))
                        cache.put()
                        params = {
                            'access_token': access_token,
                            'client_key': client.key.urlsafe(),
                            'user_key': user_key.urlsafe(),
                            'cache_key': cache.key.urlsafe(),
                        }
                        taskqueue.add(
                            url=task_url,
                            params=params,
                            target='dbworker',
                            queue_name='worker%d' % worker_number)
                        worker_number = (worker_number + 1) % 6
```

And the task_url will lead to the following:

```
logging.info('--------------------- Process File ---------------------')
        user_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.request.get('user_key'))
        client_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.request.get('client_key'))
        cache_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.request.get('cache_key'))

        cache = cache_key.get()
        data = json.loads(cache.data)
        for property in data.values():
            logging.info(property)
            try:
                key_name = '%s%s' % (property['key1'], property['key2'])
                metadata = Metadata.get_or_insert(
                    key_name,
                    parent=user_key,
                    client_key=client_key,
                    # ... other info
                )
                metadata.put()
            except StandardError, e:
                logging.error(e.message)
```

All the tasks are running in the backend.

With such structure, it's working fine. well... most of time. **But sometimes I get this error:**

```
2013-09-19 15:10:07.788
suspended generator transaction(context.py:938) raised TransactionFailedError(The transaction could not be committed. Please try again.)
W 2013-09-19 15:10:07.788
suspended generator internal_tasklet(model.py:3321) raised TransactionFailedError(The transaction could not be committed. Please try again.)
E 2013-09-19 15:10:07.789
The transaction could not be committed. Please try again.
```

It seems to be the problem of writing into datastore too frequently? I want to find out how I can balance the pace and let the worker run smoothly... 
Also is there any other way I can improve the performance further? My queue configuration is something like this:

```
- name: worker0
  rate: 120/s
  bucket_size: 100
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing single entities at a time.

How about modifing your code to write in batches using `ndb.put_multi`  that will reduce the round trip time for each transaction.

And why are you using get_or_insert as you are overwriting the record each time. You might as well just write.  Both of these will reduce the workload a lot

Comment: I just did a try of put_multi, looks like it helps! The reason I'm using get_or_insert is to avoid duplicate of data. I'm recognising each entry as unique by key_name.. unless you know a better way to keep the unique property.

Comment: concerning about unique id. If there's a duplicate in the entity list, how will put_multi handle that?

Comment: You could easily remove duplicates from the list. However you will never get duplicate records because you are using key name, in which case you will just over write the same entity.

Comment: In addition get_or_insert is also expensive as it is inside a transaction (involves a get  and a put). In your case you can blindly write.